# Macros em coordenadas relativas ao textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso inserir algumas macros em uma área de texto, estas macros podem ser inseridos em qualquer lugar do campo, atualmente eu apenas utilizo um `append` que apenas coloca a macro no começo.

Estou pensando em pegar as coordenadas do click com `clientX - ClientY` e quando for inserir a macro utilizar estas coordenadas para inserção.

**Exemplo:**

```js
 $("#inserirMacro").click(function() {
   // Pega o macro selecionado.
   var macro = $("#macros :selected").text();
   // Inseri o macro no  começo do campo textarea
   $('#campo').append(macro);
 });

 // Pega as coordenadas do click no textArea.
 $("#campo").mousedown(function(e) {
   console.log(e.clientX + ' ClientX ' + e.clientY + ' ClientY');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="macros">
  <option>[NOMECLIENTE]</option>
  <option>[CPF]</option>
  <option>[TELEFONE]</option>
  <option>[TELEFONE2]</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="inserirMacro">Inserir</button>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" id="campo"></textarea>
```

Como posso usar estas coordenadas para fazer a inserção das macros nos lugares corretos ?

Comment: Para colunas eu não sei, mas para linhas você pode adicionar um "\n" para trocar a linha.

Comment: Desenvolvi um versão rápida do que você precisa, veja no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/p0drL72g/). Ao meu ver, do jeito que você quer fazer vai dar trabalho, o posicionamento no `<textarea>` vai ser muito relativo a tamanho da font e tamanho da string, além de que você vai ter que varrer todo o `<textarea>` para adequar a nova string que for inserida e verificar se não vai sobrepor uma já existente, uma alternativa, talvez mais fácil, para oque você quer será o **drag-and-drop**.

Comment: @devgaspa sua solução é inviável, você esta transformando todo textarea em um drag-and-drop, como o usuário vai digitar o texto dele? tem que lembrar que isso ai poderia ser um documento no word qualquer.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues me perdoe, interpretei sua intenção errado, mas a lógica para localizar o  x~y e inserir no `<textarea>` é por este caminho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, acredito que seja melhor pegar a posição do cursor no `textarea`.

```js
var selection = {};
selection.Start = 0;
selection.End = 0;

var campo = $("#campo");
var inserirMacro = $("#inserirMacro");
var macros = $("#macros");

inserirMacro.click(function() {
  // Pega o macro selecionado.
  var macro = macros.children(":selected").text();
  var pre = campo.val().substring(0, selection.Start);
  var pos = campo.val().substring(selection.End);  
  campo.val(pre + macro + pos);  
  
  selection.End = selection.Start += macro.length;
  campo.prop("selectionStart", selection.Start);
  campo.prop("selectionEnd", selection.End);
  campo.focus();
});

campo.on("keyup keypress blur input", function () {
  selection.Start = campo.prop("selectionStart");
  selection.End = campo.prop("selectionEnd");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="macros">
  <option>[NOMECLIENTE]</option>
  <option>[CPF]</option>
  <option>[TELEFONE]</option>
  <option>[TELEFONE2]</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="inserirMacro">Inserir</button>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" id="campo"></textarea>
```

neste caso a macro será inserida na região da `textarea` que o usuário estava trabalhando.

Comment: Bacana demais! você sabe por que quando e inserido no meio de um conteúdo o restante dele é "selecionado"  exemplo "helloWorld", insira um macro no "W"

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, qual o browser que esta utilizando? tentei inserir a macro [NOMECLIENTE] entre ao final da palavra `Hello` em `HelloWolrd`, o resultado foi `Hello[NOMECLIENTE]World`, o restante do texto não ficou selecionado e o cursor foi deslocado para depois da macro... em todo caso vou tentar realizar uma melhoria.

Comment: Aconteceu nas Ultimas versões do Firefox 44.0.2 e Google Chrome 48.0.2564

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, realizei uma pequena alteração/melhoria, caso algum texto esteja selecionado, a macro irá substituir o texto selecionado... por exemplo... caso selecione `o W` em `Hello World` e insira a macro `[NOMECLIENTE]`, o resultado será `Hell[NOMECLIENTE]orld`

Comment: Ficou show, é isso mesmo, olha só o que eu estava fazendo em vez de ter esta opção de inserir macro: http://s15.postimg.org/e3erimb6z/macro.png uhauah, agora vai ficar bem melhor.